# Condition for splitting the integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I wanted to ask what are the conditions for splitting a definite improper integral?

For example, is it true that $$ \int_{0}^{\infty}(f(x)+g(x)) ~dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)~dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}g(x)~dx $$

If both integrals are individually convergent and are continuous throughout the domain, and if not, what are the conditions?

Comment: Now that, if any two of them converge, then the remaining third also converges.

Comment: I didn't quite understand sir. What remaining third are you talking about?

Comment: English is not my native tongue, so I might have used incorrect expression. What I intended was that, if any two of $$\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(x)+g(x)) \, \mathrm{d}x, \qquad \int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x, \qquad \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$$ converge, then all the three converge as well.

Comment: Okay, that is fine, but is it always true that the first integral equals the sum of 2nd and 3rd?

Comment: That should hold as soon as all the integrals make sense, thanks to the linearity of integration.

Comment: Like when I am doing improper integrals, i want to split them to make it easy (for example partial fractions sometimes), but I have been told that one cannot split the integrals like that, there are certain conditions.

Comment: I am pretty sure that whoever told that to you was concerned about the fact that the convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} (f(x)+g(x))\,\mathrm{d}x$ alone does not guarantee the existence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} g(x) \,\mathrm{d}x$. A silly example is: $$\int_{0}^{\infty} (x + (-x)) \,\mathrm{d}x \stackrel{?}{=} \int_{0}^{\infty} x \,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{0}^{\infty} (-x) \,\mathrm{d}x$$ but of course there are much more subtle examples in practice. So, a careless manipulation may lead to an expression of the form $\infty - \infty$, which is an indeterminate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are each Riemann integrable on $[0,b]$ for every $b > 0$, then $f(x) + g(x)$ is also Riemann integrable there, and $$ \int_0^b (f(x) + g(x))\; dx = \int_0^b f(x)\; dx + \int_0^b g(x)\; dx$$
By definition,

$$\eqalign{\int_0^\infty (f(x) + g(x))\; dx &= \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b (f(x) + g(x))\; dx\cr
&= \lim_{b \to \infty} \left(\int_0^b f(x)\; dx + \int_0^b g(x)\; dx \right)\cr
&=  \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_0^b f(x)\; dx + \lim_{b \to \infty}\int_0^b g(x)\; dx \cr
&= \int_0^\infty f(x)\; dx + \int_0^\infty g(x)\; dx}$$
if those last two improper integrals exist.

However, it can happen that the improper integrals of $f$ and $g$ don't exist, but that of $f+g$ does.